# Не работает umask

Tags: linux, c

Странно работает umask, файла 123 не существует до выполнения программы(каждый раз удаляю), и получаю каждый раз разные флаги, что делаю не так?

```
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <unistd.h>  
#include <sys/stat.h>  
#include <sys/types.h>  
#include <fcntl.h>


int main(int c, char **v)  
{  
        int fd;  
        umask(0666);  
        fd = open("./123", O_CREAT);  
        close(fd);  
        return 0;  
}
```

```
ls -la ./123
--ws-ws--T 1 fedor fedor 0 ноя 23 00:23 123
```

добавил с использованием 3 аргумента у open
теперь код выглядит так

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <unistd.h>  
#include <sys/stat.h>  
#include <sys/types.h>  
#include <fcntl.h>  
  
  
int main(int c, char **v)  
{  
        int fd;  
        umask(0666);  
        fd = open("./123", O_CREAT, 0666);  
        close(fd);  
        return 0;  
}
```

вывод ls-a следующий

```
ls -la  
----------  1 fedor fedor     0 ноя 23 10:06 123
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`umask` - блокирует разрешения, а не даёт. В функцию `open` **нужно** добавить флаги `O_RDONLY`, `O_WRONLY`, или `O_RDWR`. А флаг `O_TRUNC` позволить этот файл очистить.

```
umask(0111);
fd = open("./123", O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC, 0666 );
```

этот код с маской `0111` запретит разрешение исполнения и при открытия файла его обнулит.

Answer (score 1):

[man 2 open](https://linux.die.net/man/2/open) -- `int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);`

Вы 3-й аргумент (mode, т.е. rwx, на которые и воздействует umask) упустили, он обязателен при создании файла, а у вас его значение не определено, вот и меняется от запуска к запуску

Comment: Стоит уточнить, что в том же мане есть `int open(const char *pathname, int flags);`, но на деле объявление имеет вид `int open(const char *pathname,int flags,...);`, поэтому ошибок компиляции нет. См. https://stackoverflow.com/q/2685933/6944845 и https://stackoverflow.com/q/57411585/6944845.

Comment: поправил код, новый код в вопросе, но все равно не работает

Comment: @butleger, единички в той маске, что вы передаете в `umask()` означают, что данную привилегию нужно убрать. (из manpage open -- `the mode of the created file is (mode & ~umask).  Note that this mode applies only to future accesses of the newly created  file;  the open() call that creates a read-only file may well return a read/write file descriptor.`) / т.е. если вызвать umask(0), то права на создаваемый файл будут полностью соответствовать правам (mode), передаваемым в open